# Granularité VS granulosité

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, informatique

J'ai trouvé dans un article le terme "granulosité" dans un contexte informatique. J'étais plus habitué à granularité pour l'équivalent de l'anglais "granularity". 
Y a-t-il une différence entre "granularité" et "granulosité" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est la même différence que celle, ténue si l'on s'en tient aux définitions des dictionnaires, qui existe entre ***[granulaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/granulaire)***<sup>1</sup> et ***[granuleux](http://granuleux)***<sup>2</sup>...

J'aurais tendance à dire que quelque chose de ***granuleux*** a un aspect plus irrégulier, plus  « rugueux » que quelque chose de ***granulaire***.

***Granuleux*** semble plus souvent employé pour décrire l'aspect d'un objet, parfois de façon péjorative (aspect granuleux, dépôts granuleux, sable granuleux) tandis que ***granulaire*** semble plus souvent utilisé pour décrire de manière plus scientifique la structure d'un objet (mélange granulaire, matériau granulaire, milieu granulaire).

En informatique, on parle de **granularité** pour décrire le degré de séparation en entités indépendantes de composants logiciels. Je n'ai jamais entendu **granulosité** dans ce contexte.

<sub><sup>**1**</sup></sub> <sub>Qui est en petits grains; qui se compose de petits grains.</sub>
<sub><sup>**2**</sup></sub> <sub>Qui est fragmenté, divisé en petits grains.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Définition](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/granuleux/) de Granuleux:

> Constitué de petits grains.

[Définition](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/granulaire/) de Granulaire:

> Composé de grains très fins.

La différence serait donc minime, il serait juste question de la taille des grains qui pourrait être aussi bien petite (si la surface est granuleuse), que microscopique dans le cas d'une surface granulaire.

***Note:*** la version anglaise de ces deux Adjectif est **granular** et ne différencie pas l'un de l'autre, pouvant donc supposer qu'ils signifient la même chose chez nos voisins anglais.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que la taille des grains joue de rôle dans le choix des termes.

Comment: J'ai en effet un doute là dessus, chaque dictionnaire ayant une définition sensiblement différente, c'est pourquoi j'ai ajouté une **note** pour nuancer mes propos. Pensez-vous qu'il serait plus juste de supprimer ma phrase a propos de l'éventuelle taille des grains?

Comment: Comme tu veux, ou au moins employer le conditionnel (la différence serait donc minime...)

Comment: Très bien, j'ai mis à jour ma réponse (an mettant la phrase au conditionnel) merci pour vos retours :)